# GET request throws error after app implemented SSL: Mixed Content: This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS"

Tags: angularjs, http, ssl, https, flask

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/dashboard' was
>   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://api.example.com/inventory/10/'. This request has been blocked;
>   the content must be served over HTTPS.

We have this Angular web app that runs with Flask on the back-end.
Everything was working fine until we implemented SSL. Afterwards, we keep getting this strange error everywhere.

Now, the $http.get request in my dashboard.js is definitely calling "https://api.example.com/inventory/10" in the code below and yet the error is claiming that we are trying to request "http" instead.

```
$http.get($rootScope.baseUrl+'/inventory/' + item.id)
```

where rootScope.baseUrl is "https://api.example.com".

It's really weird because some GET requests ARE going through from our web application to our back-end, but some requests are throwing this weird error.

Here's the header that gets an error in our Network tab of the console in chrome.

> Request URL:https://api.example.com/inventory/10 Request Headers
>   Provisional headers are shown Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
>   Origin:https://www.example.com
>   Referer:https://www.example.com/dashboard

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302160/https-with-http-in-angular-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a weird case that came down to removing a forward slash from the end of a URL fixing everything. Somehow, whenever we made a GET request using $http in Angular like baseurl + inventory.id + "/", it would make a http request but as soon as remove that slash, it would make the https request correctly.

Still so confused

Comment: I wonder if some kind of URL rewriting is going on, and resolving the URL to an absolute URL with http://...

Answer (score 2):

I think the root of the problem is in server redirects. I was able to resolve same issue with `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')` setting for Django (its running behind AWS balancer). Here is [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header).